# Error attempting to uninstall Kibana with Brew

Tags: homebrew

I installed Kibana on myb mac using brew.  The kibana version is too recent for my ES cluster so I was going to uninstall and reinstall an older version.

When I issue this command:

```
brew uninstall kibana
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/kibana
```

I'm absolutely positive I installed using "brew install kibana" Is there anything I can do to uninstall kibana so I can reinstall an older version?

Answer (score 1):

If you list directories inside Cellar folder, you will find a folder named `kibana-full`. You need to run

```
brew uninstall kibana-full
```

Comment: Alternatively, run `brew uninstall elastic/tap/kibana-full`